# It’s high as a f**king kite

Tags: meaning

> ‘I wouldn’t go down there sir. It’s high as a f**king kite.’
>   Creeley wasn’t exaggerating. Even in the relative cool of the late afternoon the smell wafting off the farm was stomach turning.

Does the phrase  "It’s high as a f**king kite" really mean that "it smells terribly" as is apparent from the context of my sample. I have tried to make some research regarding this phrase but without success.

Comment: Yes, I would agree. See http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/strong-smelling, then click the  "as in smelly" tab.

Comment: As an aside, **high as a f*cking kite** can also mean "very stoned on drugs". Not that it applies here.

Answer (score 3):

It means *high* in the sense of

> **high** *adj*
>   4 b. Having a bad smell; malodorous.

See http://www.thefreedictionary.com/high.

Note that it uses the familiar cliché **high as a kite** to intensify the degree to which the smell was bad. **Edit**: Also note that "high as a kite" is most often used to describe someone in an extreme state of intoxication. The usage here ignores the normal usage to pivot to this new meaning, which may or may not work: as it's reported speech, the sloppiness may be attributed to the character's imprecise use of language, or it may be that the character is making a joke by extending the common metaphor.

Note: This does not mean it smells *terribly* (adverb), but that it smells *terrible* (adjective). *Terribly* would modify the verb *smell*, not the location mentioned in the passage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I do not understand your explanation regarding terrible/terrible. How does the farm smell? It smells terribly.  Or terrible?

Comment: A farm smells terrible, not terribly. A skyscraper looks big, not bigly. The sun feels hot, not hotly. An adjective modifies a noun, but an adverb modifies an adjective or another adverb. The farm contains no apparatus for smelling, so you are describing the *smell* (noun) of the farm, not the manner in which it uses a faculty it does not possess to smell with.

Comment: @bart-leby: Verbs relating to the senses take predicate adjective complements. The food tastes *delicious*, not deliciously.  The fabric feels *rough*, not roughly.   The verbs are making a statement about the thing perceived, not about the act of perception.

Comment: Note: I should have added *verb* to what an adverb modifies.

Comment: @bart-leby They say the farm smells terrible, but I didn't notice when I visited because I had a cold and therefore smelled terribly.